# Ajax - prevent click on a successful ajax request

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a video thumbnail on my page, with a little icon "Thumbs Down". When you click on that, another thumbnail shows, replacing the other. User can do that as much as they want.

My code is now working only the first time. HTML:

```
<a href="/change/videos/{{ video.video_id}}/thumbsdown/" data-sort="sort" data-page="page" class="dislike_black" title="I dislike this"></a>
```

AJAX:

```
$('.dislike_black').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   alert("test");
   var $aTag = $(this);
   $.ajax({
       url: $aTag.attr('href'),
       type: "POST",
       data: {
          "sort": $aTag.data('sort'),
          "page": $aTag.data('page')
       },
       success: function(response) {
          $aTag.parents("li").replaceWith(response);
      }
   });
});
```

When I click the icon the first time, its all fine, triggers the alert, the second time thought, no alert, and the browser is loading the href link.

I tried .preventDefault(); on the success and the complete event, but its not working.

Any hint on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your content is dynamically created so, depending on the version of jQuery you are using, you need the `jQuery.live()` or `jQuery.on()` method

> **jQuery.live() *since jQuery 1.3*** an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.
>
> **jQuery.on()  *since jQuery 1.7*** - Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

### Sample

**jQuery.live()**

```
$('.dislike_black').live("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   alert("test");
   var $aTag = $(this);
   $.ajax({
       url: $aTag.attr('href'),
       type: "POST",
       data: {
          "sort": $aTag.data('sort'),
          "page": $aTag.data('page')
       },
       success: function(response) {
          $aTag.parents("li").replaceWith(response);
      }
   });
});
```

**jQuery.on()**

```
$('.dislike_black').on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   alert("test");
   var $aTag = $(this);
   $.ajax({
       url: $aTag.attr('href'),
       type: "POST",
       data: {
          "sort": $aTag.data('sort'),
          "page": $aTag.data('page')
       },
       success: function(response) {
          $aTag.parents("li").replaceWith(response);
      }
   });
});
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
- [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: `live` is deprecated its better to switch to delegate if version 1.7+ of jQuery is not available

Comment: I think i covered the versions in my answer. What you think ? Thanks for repsonse

Comment: yup you covered the versions well +1 for that but `.live` is deprecated in the latest versions of jquery so its advised to use `.delegate` instead of `.live`,

Comment: You should always avoid using `live` instead use `delegate`. Because of its known issues it is being deprecated.

Comment: thanks, but `delegate` is from 1.4.2, `on` from 1.7 BUT `live` is from 1.3. So i think in future i will cover `delegate` too. But i think the right order is `live` > `delegate` > `on`. Not ?

Answer (score 3):

Because you are replacing the dom which contains the anchor itself by new html in the ajax success handler. In this case you should use `on` which will attach event handler to parent or document element whatever you pass as the root element but will trigger the event only on the matching selector which you pass as the second argument. Try this.

```
$(document).on('click', '.dislike_black', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   alert("test");
   var $aTag = $(this);
   $.ajax({
       url: $aTag.attr('href'),
       type: "POST",
       data: {
          "sort": $aTag.data('sort'),
          "page": $aTag.data('page')
       },
       success: function(response) {
          $aTag.parents("li").replaceWith(response);
      }
   });
});
```

`.on()` reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/ (Ver. 1.7+)

If you are using older version of jQuery you can still achieve this using `delegate` method whose syntax is same as `on` but just the first 2 arguments are interchanged.

```
$(document).delegate('.dislike_black', 'click', function(e) {
  //Your code here
});
```

`.delegate()` reference: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: You are using older version of jQuery. Use the alternative approach from my answer using `delegate`.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$(document).delegate('.dislike_black',"click",function(e) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using event delegation.

```
// older jquery, use this line:
// $( ".dislike_black" ).live( "click", function ( e ) {
$( document ).on( "click", ".dislike_black", function ( e ) {
   e.preventDefault();
   alert( "test" );
   var $aTag = $( this );
   $.ajax( {
       url : $aTag.attr( 'href' ),
       type : "POST",
       data : {
          "sort" : $aTag.data( 'sort' ),
          "page" : $aTag.data( 'page' )
       },
       success: function ( response ) {
          $aTag.parents( "li" ).replaceWith( response );
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Then you are using an older jquery, comment out that line and uncomment the line above it.

Comment: @RébeccaO'Brien because probably you are using an older version of jquery, for `.on` to work you need version `1.7+`